# data extraction from complex data file using Python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a large txt file, which contains blocks of data as follows:

```
AB x u z

1  0.00 1.00 4.23

2  0.34 2.33 1.44

3  4.23 3.55 6.22

AC x u z



AB x u z

1  0.88 1.00 4.27

2  0.36 2.33 1.44

3  4.23 3.55 6.22

AC x u z



AB x u z

1  0.66 1.77 8.23

2  0.44 2.33 1.44

3  4.23 3.55 6.44

AC x u z



AB x u z

1  0.44 1.99 8.22

2  0.34 2.33 1.44

3  4.23 3.55 6.22

AC x u z
```

I am using Python 2.7 (new to this language), I simply need to extract the lines between the line "AB x u z" and "AC x u v" for, say the 3rd data block, and print these lines to another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
stored = []
with open("test.py") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("AB x u z"):
            block = []
        elif line.startswith("AC x u z"):
            stored.append(block)
        else:
            block.append(line)
```

The idea is to construct a list of blocks (`stored`), each block containing the lines between `"AB x u z"` and `"AC x u z"`. Note that you may want to get rid of the empty lines by using

```
elif line.strip():
    block.append(line)
```

as the last test.

Because we're using a `for...` loop, we don't load your whole file in memory (which may be a problem if it's large). The `with...` statement will automatically close your file when it's read.

**EDIT**
As pointed out in a comment, `stored` will eventually have the whole file in memory. However, if you need to store only some specific blocks, you can always use a counter that you'll increment each time you find a closing line `"AC x u z"`: if the value of this counter meets a given requirement, say, `counter=3`, store the block, otherwise keep iterating.

Comment: Using `stored` loads  the whole file in memory. The OP wants to prints lines to another file from *"the 3rd data block"* i.e., you can drop everything except the 3rd block and break after you found it. `line` contains a newline so to skip blank lines you could use `elif line.strip():`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Using `stored` in effect stores the whole content, but in an organized way, and nothing prevents the OP to store only the blocks that are needed. And good point on the `elsif line.split()`, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

@paulc, you've probably sorted this out already but I just wanted to share my code being a 'newer-bie'

```
BLOCK_THREE = '3'
outStr = ""

# Read Data File
with open('rough_data.txt', 'r') as srcFile:
    for lnReader in srcFile:
        if lnReader.startswith(BLOCK_THREE):
            outStr += lnReader # lnReader reads each line as a String
        else:
            pass

# Write Data to a file
ofile = open('extracts2.txt', 'w')
ofile.write(u'' + outStr)
ofile.close()
print 'end'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
F = open ('yourfile.txt', 'r')

data = F.read.split('\n\n') #Assuming that there's two newlines between every 'block'
```

This will give you a list (data) containing a 'block' in every place of the list.